# Approximate intermediate value theorem in pure constructive mathematics

Tags: lo.logic, real-analysis, constructive-mathematics

The ordinary intermediate value theorem (IVT) is not provable in constructive mathematics.  To show this, one can construct a Brouwerian "weak counterexample" and also promote it to a precise countermodel: the basic idea is that the root may not depend continuously or computably on the function, since a small perturbation in a function's value may cause a root to appear or disappear.

There are, however, many variants of the IVT that are constructively provable.  This question is about the *approximate* IVT, which says that if $f(a)<0<f(b)$ then for any $\epsilon>0$ there is a point $x$ with $|f(x)|<\epsilon$.  It seems to be well-known that the approximate IVT can be proven assuming either (1) countable (or maybe dependent) choice, or (2) that $f$ is uniformly continuous.  [This paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397502007077) contains many versions of approximate IVT using somewhat weaker hypotheses such as "strong continuity" of $f$.  But I would like to know:

> Can the approximate IVT be proven constructively about an arbitrary (pointwise) continuous function $f$, without using any form of choice or excluded middle (e.g. in the mathematics valid in any elementary topos with NNO)?

If the answer is no, I would like to see at least a weak counterexample, or even better a specific countermodel (e.g. a topos in which it fails).

**Edit:** To clarify, the functions in question are from the real numbers (or some interval therein) to the real numbers.  I'll accept an answer that defines "the real numbers" either as equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences or as Dedekind cuts (but not as a "setoid" of Cauchy sequences).

Comment: In most varieties of constructive math, the functions which are defined on [a,b] and provably pointwise continuous on [a,b] are also provably uniformly continuous on [a,b]; the inferential rule is valid even though the implication is not provable.  Or so I suspect, though I've only seen proofs of related things and not of this specifically.  In any case, because of this I wouldn't expect to see a weak counterexample.

Comment: @MattF. I thought I'd seen a weak counterexample to the statement "every pointwise continuous function on [a,b] is uniformly continuous", though I don't remember it offhand.  But in any case, as I said, a strong countermodel would be even better.

Comment: For anyone looking for a counterexample let me remark that the most naive example does not work: Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a fixed continuous function. Let $X$ be a metric space. The object of Dedekind real numbers in the sheaf topos $\mathrm{Sh}(X)$ is the sheaf $\mathcal{C}_X$ of continuous functions on $X$. The function $f$ induces  a morphism $\mathcal{C}_X \to \mathcal{C}_X$ by postcomposition, that is internally a function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. From the internal point of view, this function is continuous and verifies the strong IVT.

Comment: Claim:  Let $x,y$ range over $[a,b]$ and $m,n$ over $\mathbf{N}$.  If $\phi(m,n,x) \rightarrow \phi(m+1,n,x)$, then we can transform a constructive proof of $\forall n\ \forall x\ \exists m\ \phi(m,n,x)$ into a constructive proof of $\forall n\ \exists m\ \forall x\ \phi(m,n,x)$.  Special case with $$\phi(m,n,x) = \forall y\ ( |x-y|<1/m \rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)|<1/n)$$:  if pointwise continuity is constructively provable then so is uniform continuity.  Question for the crowd:  is there a known result from which the claim follows?

Comment: I found a reference for the claim:  Michael Beeson, either his 1977 paper, http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S000348437780003X, secs 2.2, 2.6, 2.8, or in a bit more generality in his 1985 book.  It also requires the extensionality of $\phi$, which is true here.

Comment: @MattF. This is called the fan rule. Kleene realizability/recursive mathematics gives a counter model to the fan rule. https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/realizability However, it does model CAC.

Comment: @BasSpitters, you're right, and now I see that section 2.7 of Beeson's paper references this as a counterexample to uniform continuity.  I don't understand that counterexample yet, so if you do you're welcome to write it up as an answer.

Comment: Of course, a function that's continuous but not uniformly so is not necessarily a counterexample to IVT, but it might turn out to be one.

Comment: To construct a function that's not uniformly continuous, one typically uses Kleene's first realizability model and considers Kleene's singular tree. By embedding Cantor space into [0,1] one obtains an unbounded function, which therefore cannot be uniformly continuous. This should be in Beeson's book. It can also be found in Troelstra/van Dalen or Bridges/Richman - Varieties of constructive mathematics. I seem to recall that one can combine realizability with forcing to obtain a model without countable choice and fan. However, I do not recall the source. Still, this does not yet contradict IVT.

Comment: Just a quick sanity check: let $a$ be a real such that $\neg (a<0\wedge a=0\wedge a>0)$. Then the function $f(x)=ax$ is the well-known counterexample to the extreme value theorem. Now take the function $g(x)=f(x)-\frac{a}{3}$. Is this a counterexample to IVT? If we multiply it by a huge number would this give a counterexample even to the approximate form of the IVT?

Comment: @MikhailKatz I assume you mean $\neg (a<0 \vee a=0 \vee a>0)$, or equivalently $\neg(a<0) \wedge \neg(a=0) \wedge \neg(a>0)$.  Can such an $a$ really exist?  I thought $\neg(a<0)$ was the same as $a\ge 0$, and similarly $\neg(a>0)$ the same as $a\le 0$, which together imply $a=0$.

Comment: What or where is the proof that Pointwise Continuity + Dependent Choice --> Approximate IVT?

Comment: @MattF. it's in Bishop's *Foundations of constructive analysis*.  Basically you bisect the interval like classically, only you test the function values at the midpoints for being $< \epsilon$ or $> -\epsilon$ instead of $\le 0$ or $\ge 0$.  Using DC you obtain a sequence of nested intervals $[a_n,b_n]$ of halving length with intersection $c$.  If $f(c)<\epsilon$ then by continuity, $f(x)<\epsilon$ on a sufficiently small $[a_n,b_n]$, whence $a_n$ or $b_n$ is the desired point $d$ with $|f(d)|<\epsilon$.

Comment: That's interesting, I hadn't remembered it from Bishop & Bridges.  Perhaps we can eliminate the use of DC.

Comment: Would "[coalgebraic reals](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/coalgebra+of+the+real+interval)" be acceptable ones too?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე, there's at least one way to do the coalgebraic reals constructively that ends up equivalent to the Dedekind reals; this is shown at the end of section D4.7 in *Sketches of an Elephant*.  So that would certainly be acceptable.  If there's a way to do coalgebraic reals constructively that doesn't end up equivalent to the Dedekind or Cauchy reals, then that wouldn't really be quite what I'm looking for, but it would nevertheless be interesting.

Comment: @Mike, are you sure that Bishop's proof of IVT from DC applies to any pointwise continuous function?  If you've checked the proof, then I beleive you, but you can't rely on Bishop's infallibilty; in his book (and in the Bishop & Bridges rewrite, although not in some other work by Bridges), ‘continuous’ means ‹pointwise continuous and (uniformly continuous on compact intervals)›.

Comment: Well, regardless of what Bishop may or may not say, your proof sketch certainly looks valid.  From a uniformly-continuous perspective, it goes on unnecessarily long; you could stop when the interval length is less than the δ obtained from ϵ by the modulus of uniform continuity (which is why uniform continuity requires only finitely many choices).  But by going on forever, you get a point at which you can apply mere pointwise continuity.  (I guess that you already know all of that.  For that matter, I may have known it once too and forgotten.)

Comment: If it inspires anybody, here is a version of the IVT that applies to pointwise continuous functions in any topos (not an answer to Mike's question, but it might give people ideas):  If every value of _f_ is positive or negative, then every value of _f_ is positive or every value of _f_ is negative.  This is basically a contrapositive of the classical (non-approximate) theorem, and while it is rather weak, it's strong enough for some things.  (Basically, if somebody says something intuitively obvious that doesn't require a point _c_ yet proves it with the IVT, then you can probably use this.)

Comment: (Proof: by contradiction is valid here; use interval halving; your hand is forced at every stage, no choices to make, so you can go forever; apply continuity at the limiting point _c_.  Since this is a proof by contradiction, this point does not actually exist, of course.)

Comment: @TobyBartels I don't have Bishop's book in front of me, so I don't know what he actually said; I actually reconstructed that sketch from an even briefer sketch in another paper that cited Bishop for it.  (-:

Comment: Actually, you can make the contrapositive IVT more interesting if you phrase it yet another way:  If a real-valued function _f_ defined on a real interval has both positive and negative values, but only positive or negative values, then it has a point of discontinuity, and you can actually find this point by interval-halving.  This works in any ω-topos (that is any topos with a natural-numbers object).

Comment: @MikeShulman, sorry about the late response to your comment.  Yes, that's what I meant ("or" instead of "and"). Such numbers can exist in certain intuitionistic settings; see a discussion for example in [this article](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s11787-014-0102-8).

Comment: @MikhailKatz - That article is behind a paywall.  Can you explain (perhaps in a chat room) how such a *real number* can exist -- not just an element of some real-number-like ring such as the line object in SDG, I mean an actual Cauchy or Dedekind real number?

Comment: Mike, this is a completely routine thing out of Troelstra--van Dalen.  The only advantage of the article I mentioned is that it is shorter and focuses on the issue more than Troelstra-van Dalen. Once you start talking about "existence" you leave the company of constructive mathematicians, I think :-) Try the links given [here](http://u.cs.biu.ac.il/~katzmik/infinitesimals.html#14b).

Comment: @MikhailKatz Constructive mathematicians talk about existence all the time; in fact one might say they talk about it more than classical mathematicians do (who care more about failure to nonexist).  I looked at the arXiv link, and the only thing I could find relevant was section 5 saying that trichotomy for reals is equivalent to LPO.  But the negation of LPO doesn't entail the *existence* of a real number violating trichotomy, only that not all real numbers satisfy trichotomy: $\neg\forall \neq \exists \neg$ is a hallmark of constructive logic.

Comment: Similarly LLPO is equivalent to $\forall x, (x\le 0) \vee (x\ge 0)$, and in that case it is possible for there to exist a real number that is neither $\le 0$ nor $\ge 0$, as discussed in that section.  But I really think it is not possible to violate trichotomy.  To say $x>0$ means there exists a positive rational bounding $x$ away from 0.  If this is false, then $x<q$ for all positive rationals $q$.  Similarly, if $\neg(x<0)$ then $x>q$ for all negative rationals $q$, hence $|x|<q$ for all positive rationals $q$.  No matter whether $x$ is a Cauchy or Dedekind real, this entails $x=0$.

Comment: Mike, my point was merely that one can't prove the extreme value theorem or the intermediate value theorem without using LPO. Is this not correct?

Comment: @MikhailKatz as mentioned in the original question, there are many versions of the IVT and many ways to prove it.  For the approximate IVT I asked about here, as I mentioned, one standard way to prove it uses nothing but countable choice, which does not imply LPO.  In the answer below, Matt F. gives a way to prove it without using even countable choice.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here's a constructive proof of the approximate Intermediate Value Theorem from pointwise continuity, not relying on Dependent Choice and not relying on a setoid construction of the reals.

**Theorem:**  If $f$ is pointwise continuous with $f(a)<0, \ f(b)>0,\ \epsilon>0$ then there is some $x$ with $|f(x)|<\epsilon$.

**Proof:  Define** the following inductively:
 
$$a_1 = a$$
$$b_1 = b$$
$$c_n = (a_n+b_n) / 2$$
$$d_n = \max( 0, \min( \textstyle\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{ f(c_n)}{\epsilon}, 1))$$
$$a_{n+1} = c_n - d_n (b-a)/2^n $$
$$b_{n+1} = b_n - d_n (b-a)/2^n$$
Then $b_n - a_n = (b-a)/2^{n-1}.$
 
So the $c_n$'s converge to some $c.$

By pointwise continuity at $c$,
let $\delta$ be such that $ |x-c|<\delta$
implies $|f(x)-f(c)| < \epsilon.$

**Claim**:  
For any $m\in\mathbb{N}$, either (i) $\exists j \le m,\ |f(c_j)| < \epsilon$
or (ii) $f(a_m) < 0 $ and$ f(b_m) > 0$.

**Proof of theorem from claim:**

Choose $c_m$ such that $|c-c_m| < \delta / 2$ and $(a-b)/2^m < \delta / 2$, and apply the claim.

In the first case of the claim, the theorem is immediate.

In the second case of the claim, 
 $$ |c-a_m| \le |c-c_m| + |c_m-a_m| < \delta, \text{ so }|f(c)-f(a_m)| < \epsilon$$
$$ |c-b_m| \le |c-c_m| + |c_m-b_m| < \delta, \text{ so }|f(c)-f(b_m)| < \epsilon$$
So $f(c)$ is within $\epsilon$ of both a negative and a positive number, and $|
f(c)| < \epsilon$, QED.

**Proof of claim** by induction on $m$.
The base case is given by $ f(a) < 0, \ f(b) > 0.$

Now assume the claim for $m$. In case (i), for some $ j < m,\ |f(c_j)| < \epsilon$, and the inductive step is trivial.

In case (ii), use trichotomy with either
$f(c_m) < -\epsilon/2, \ |f(c_m)| < \epsilon$, or $f(c_m) > \epsilon/2.$
 
If $|f(c_m)| < \epsilon$, then the inductive step is again trivial.
 
If $f(c_m) > \epsilon/2$, then
                $$d_m = 1$$
$$a_{m+1} = a_m, \text{ so }f(a_{m+1}) < 0$$
$$b_{m+1} = c_m,\text{ so } f(b_{m+1}) > 0$$

If $f(c_m) < - \epsilon/2$, then
                $$d_m = 0$$
$$a_{m+1} = c_m, \text{ so }f(a_{m+1}) < 0$$
$$b_{m+1} = b_m,\text{ so } f(b_{m+1}) > 0$$

**QED** (claim and theorem).

I think this one works; I look forward to seeing what MO says.

Comment: The claim is not a statement of the form "for all $i$", so I don't know how to prove it by induction.  Do you mean the claim to be "for all $m$, ..." and then prove it by induction on $m$, with the choice of a particular $m$ such that $|c-c_m|<\delta/2$ and $(a-b)/2^m <\delta/2$ coming *after* the claim?

Comment: You can prove it for all integer $m$ if you want. Or, since a particular $m$ is determined before the claim, you can prove that particular statement by starting with the base case and applying the inductive step $m-1$ times.

Comment: Ok.  The point is that the claim can't be a statement *only* about one particular $m$, since if it were you couldn't prove it by induction; but the way it's currently written, it looks as if the claim is only making a statement about one particular $m$.  I'll fix it.

Comment: And I do believe that this works!  I'll sleep on it before being too sure, but it seems right to me: the idea is that at the point when we make a "choice" in the proof, we can instead interpolate between the two options.

Comment: Don't sleep too long, or you won't be able to award the full bounty!

Comment: As far as I'm concerned it works perfectly, and the idea to "interpolate between the two options" as Mike say it is very good ! (And I spent way too much time trying to construct a counterexample....)

Comment: Beautiful! I think this is a genuinely new idea about the bisection method.

Comment: I agree, this is very nice!  Totally worth 200 rep.

Comment: @MattF., could you please contact me in real life. I think this should be published or at least presented somewhere outside of MO.

Comment: Following up on @AndrejBauer 's comment, Matt F's paper, _Interpolating Between Choices for the Approximate Intermediate Value Theorem_ is now here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.02227 May I say, it's very nice.

Comment: I tried this algorithm out "by hand" (actually interactively so I can quickly vary $a, b$ and $\epsilon$ and found that the value of $\epsilon$ has an oscillating effect on the solution: Not always does a small $\epsilon$ appear to be better. I wonder whether there is some notion of a (more) optimal choice of $\epsilon$ that will actually, for all pointwise continuous functions, work faster than the version where $d$ is either $0$ or $1$. Not sure what information can be used to get there though.

Comment: Thinking about this again: am I right that it only works for a notion of "real numbers" that is Cauchy complete (to ensure that the $c_n$'s converge to some $c$)?  So that includes the Dedekind reals, but not the naive Cauchy reals defined as equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences.

Comment: @MikeShulman, yes, this assumes Cauchy completeness.  But I am not familiar with the failure of that for the naive Cauchy reals; perhaps with an example for that failure I would see a way around the issue.

Comment: I don't have a concrete example; the problem is that given a Cauchy sequence of Cauchy reals, what you have is a sequence of *equivalence classes* of Cauchy sequences of rationals, and in the absence of countable choice there generally is no way to select representatives to obtain a sequence of actual Cauchy sequences of rationals that you can "diagonalize" to get a single Cauchy sequence of rationals to be the limit.

Comment: @MikeShulman, I would prefer to work with slightly less naive reals, defining a real as an equivalence class of Cauchy-sequences-of-rationals-with-given-moduli-of-continuity, sot that Cauchy sequences of reals converge even without countable choice.

Comment: Having a given modulus of continuity is actually the usual meaning of "Cauchy sequence" in constructive mathematics, and it's not good enough to make Cauchy sequences of reals converge, since you still have a sequence of equivalence classes of such things and have to select representatives.

Comment: @MikeShulman, let's move this to chat

Comment: Usually when I see someone say that, there is a link to a chat room...

Comment: @MikeShulman, I replied in MOchat, https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9369/mathoverflow

Comment: For avoidance of doubt, once the sliding window gets detached from both the left and the right endpoints of its parent, then the algorithm starts behaving incorrectly. The conditions behind the interval bisection algorithm get broken -- but even when that happens, it's guaranteed that the algorithm has already found the approximate root. The conclusion is that no practical advance on interval bisection has been made. The behaviour of this algorithm is *identical* to the classical algorithm before this algorithm starts sliding, at which point it behaves incorrectly and starts chasing its tail.

Answer (score 5):

*Update:  this answer was before the edit to the question rejecting this setoid approach.*

We can prove the approximate intermediate value theorem constructively using only pointwise continuity.  The proof has the same feel as $\forall x \in \mathbf{R}\ \exists n \in \mathbf{N} \ n > r$, which is constructively valid but with $n$ chosen in a way that depends on the particular rational sequence defining $x$.

A real number $x$ is defined to be a sequence of rationals $x^n$ such that $|x^m-x^n|\le 1/m+1/n$.  (Since there are no positive exponents in this proof, all positive superscripts will be these rational approximations.)  So $|x-x^n| \le 1/n$ and, e.g. we can choose the $n$ above to be $\lceil x^1 \rceil + 2.$

Now we are given $a,\ b,\ \epsilon,\ f$ as in the question.  Let $a_1=a$, $b_1=b$.

$$\text{Let }c_n = (a_n+b_n)/2.$$
$$\text{If }f(c_n)^n < 0,\text{ then let }a_{n+1} = c_n,\ b_{n+1}=b_n.$$ 
$$\text{If }f(c_n)^n \ge 0,\text{ then let }a_{n+1} = a_n,\ b_{n+1}=c_n.$$

Unlike the version referenced in the 11/16 comment, this is deterministic at each stage, so the construction of the $c$'s requires only unique choice and not dependent choice.  (If there's a hidden use of dependent choice, please let me know!)

The intervals $[a_n,b_n]$ have lengths decreasing by halves with intersection $c$.  Furthermore, $f(a_n)^n < 1/n$ and $f(b_n)^n \ge -1/n$ for all $n$.

By pointwise continuity of $f$, choose $\delta$ such that $|x-c|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon/3$.

Choose $m$ with $(a-b)2^{-m} < \delta$ and $1/m < \epsilon/3$.  Then

$$|a_m-c|<(a-b)2^{-m} < \delta, \ \text{ and }\ f(c) \le f(a_m) + \epsilon/3 \le  f(a_m)^m + 1/m + \epsilon/3 \le \epsilon.$$
By similar comparison with the $b$'s, $f(c) \ge -\epsilon$.  So $c$ is as desired to prove the approximate intermediate value theorem, QED.

Comment: This proof uses the typical Bishop trick of treating sets as setoids (set + equivalence relation). It is not valid in a topos. It is not valid in a model if intuitionistic set theory. It is not valid in homotopy type theory. You have simply circumvented the use of countable choice (you don't need dependent choice for your construction, even when you do honest equality) by replacing equality relation with an equivalence relation.

Comment: @AndrejBauer, I agree with your first and last sentences.  I might express the homotopy type theory comment as "this proof will not work if we treat the reals as in homotopy type theory".   I'll leave it to the OP to say whether this answers his question.

Comment: Andrej is right, this is not a proof about the real numbers but about Cauchy sequences -- a real number is an equivalence class of Cauchy sequences.

Comment: Downvoters, does this really qualify as an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended, or clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect answer to the original version of the question?  If the setoid approach is legitimate in constructive math, as I think it is, then "not what the OP had in mind" seems fairer than "incorrect".  Or is it just that, given the edit to the question, it would be better to remove the answer?

Comment: Please leave the answer, because someone else searching for an answer to the original question, but who _does_ want the Bishop setting, will find it useful. Also, other answers might be able to reference yours. (For reference sake, I upvoted your answer since I thought it carefully thought out and useful)

Comment: I agree with @DavidRoberts that this answer should be kept.  (I do also think that my intent could have been deduced from the question as originally asked, since I mentioned toposes, but I also agree that I should have been more clear.)  I downvoted because I don't want to award this answer the bounty, even if no other answers are given; after the bounty period is over I will be happy to remove the downvote.  (Am I misusing the system?)

Comment: @Mike I don't think you'll be able to undo your vote after a certain period of time.

Comment: The answer should be left here for future generations of constructive mathematicians. I downvoted because it's not answering what was asked (I understood Mike to be asking about toposes even though he might not have mentioned it because I know what sort of thing he's been working on lately).

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications, guys.  A non-negative, non-bounty-earning score is fine by me.

Answer (score 3):

[I just started here and do not have enough reputation to comment...so I´m kind of forced to give an answer.]

I believe there is a different way to eliminate countable choice in the proof of aIVT (approximate intermediate value theorem). I've described this way on the constructive-news forum https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/constructivenews/e3JfKk_W2jI

I'm not sure if that description is too specialist to post here. But what it boils down to is this: in Matt's first proof, using bisection, there is a hidden use of countable choice. Because to evaluate the real number $f(c_n)$, one has to pick a representative of its equivalence class. (This is brilliantly avoided in Matt's second proof).

My first attempt to avoid this involved looking at recursive mathematics. If we take $a,b$ and $f$ to be recursive, then if we pick (recursive) representatives $a', b'$ we can apply the bisection method without using countable choice. Because taking the mean is a recursive function $m(a,b)=\frac{(a+b)}{2}$, we see that every iterative construction and evaluation of $f(c_n)$ is recursive in $a', b'$.

This approach can be characterized as: `we only need countable choice because the objects that we are working with have been insufficiently specified beforehand'. In other words: we have left too much choice in $a,b$ AND $f$

However I believe there is a more general way to avoid choice in the construction of $a,b$ AND $f$. By describing R and continuous real functions in a different way, namely R as a #-quotient and continuous real functions as #-morphisms on Baire space, we can apply the bisection method without using countable choice.

The reason for this is comparable to the recursive situation. If we pick #-representatives $a'',b''$ of $a,b$
AND #-representatives $m'', f''$ of the functions $m, f$, there is no choice left in the bisection procedure using $a'', b'', m'', f''$, because composition of #-morphisms is completely deterministic.

In CLASS, INT and RUSS I believe we can prove that every continuous real function can be represented by such a #-morphism. This proof can be found in my book Natural Topology [but it really should be checked by some more people]. A preprint which I submitted to LMCS three years ago (!) is still under reviewer's consideration.

So I believe that using #-morphisms in BISH is a general way to avoid countable choice in theorems comparable to aIVT. Since #-quotient representations can be found for any Polish space, this goes a lot further than just real functions.

Comment: This may be interesting, but it does not answer the question, which was specifically about "an arbitrary pointwise continuous function".

Comment: Like I said, in CLASS, INT and RUSS we can  prove that "an arbitrary pointwise continuous function" coincides with "a #-morphism". That is why I consider my answer to be an answer. For a much more detailed answer see my reply to your same question on [constructive-news](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/constructivenews/e3JfKk_W2jI).

Comment: I still don't have enough reputation to comment on any other answer except my own... So I'll be a little creative.By the way, I said that in Matt's first proof there is a hidden use of countable choice, but it really is a hidden use of dependent choice. This is the "only" failure that I see in that answer (well, it ceases to be an answer then I suppose), and I am surprised that no one noticed the use of DC in that proof.

Comment: Oops, I hit enter when I was still editing my comment. Because I wanted to start with saying that I really think that Matt's second proof is very beautiful! I have to get the hang of MO, sorry.