# Has an uncomputable variant of the Cantor staircase ever been used in constructive logic?

Tags: lo.logic, computability-theory, topos-theory, constructive-mathematics

An open problem in choiceless constructivism is to prove that if a function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is pointwise differentiable everywhere, with $f'=0$, then $f$ is constant. See [In choiceless constructivism: If $f'=0$ then is $f$ constant?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/357064/in-choiceless-constructivism-if-f-0-then-is-f-constant).

I'm proposing a route to a negative answer to the above conjecture.

Cantor's staircase is a continuous function whose derivative is $0$ almost everywhere, but which is non-constant. The function is constant over intervals $[a/3^n, (a+1)/3^n]$.

What I'm proposing is to construct a function by exploiting the classical countability of the computable numbers $\mathbb R^c$. Let $(u_i)_{i \in \mathbb N} \in (\mathbb R^c)^{\mathbb N}$ be a sequence enumerating the computable numbers. Construct $F:\mathbb R^c \to \mathbb R^c$ as $\lim_{n \to \infty}F_n$ where $(F_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is recursively defined by:

- Let $l < u$ be a pair of uncomputable reals in $[0,1]$. Then let: $F_0:[0,l] \cup [u,1] \to \mathbb R^c, x \mapsto \begin{cases}0, & x \in [0,l] \\ 1, & x \in [u,1]. \end{cases}$
- $F_{n+1}$ by the following rule: If $u_{n}$ is in the domain of the function $F_n$, then define $F_{n+1} = F_n$. If $u_{n}$ is not in the domain of $F_n$, then pick two uncomputable numbers $l < u$ such that $[l,u]$ is not in the domain of $F_n$ and $l < u_{n} < u$; then define

$$\begin{align}
F_{n+1}&:\operatorname{dom}(F_n) \cup [l,u] \to \mathbb R^c,\\
x& \mapsto \begin{cases} \frac{1}{2}(F_n(\sup(\operatorname{dom}(F_n) \cap [0,l])) + F_n(\inf(\operatorname{dom}(F_n) \cap [u,1]))), &x \in [l,u] \\ F_n(x), &x \not \in [l,u]. \end{cases}
\end{align}$$

I don't see how an uncomputable number can be obtained from such a function, and therefore how an $x$ can be exhibited for which $F'(x)$ does not exist.

I suppose I'm suggesting that in the sentence $\forall x \in \mathbb R. f'(x)=0$, we mean to quantify only over the computable numbers. So we would need a topos in which $\mathbb R$ is just the computable numbers, perhaps. Maybe externally, the morphisms $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ need to correspond to all the continuous functions $\mathbb R^c \to \mathbb R^c$, including the one above.

Notice that in classical logic, the space of computable numbers with the Euclidean topology is totally disconnected. The failure of $f'=0$ to imply that $f$ is constant is then due to total disconnectivity.

Can this be used to settle the conjecture in the negative?

Comment: Should I ask this on a mailing list or somewhere else?

Comment: How do you define $\Omega$ without LEM?

Comment: @Trebor The $\Omega$ is in the external logic.

Comment: I am confused about the proposal. How do you intend to define the function in the topos without $\Omega$ being in the topos?

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Because it only exists in the external logic.

Comment: The internal logic of the topos does not prove the existence of an uncomputable number.

Comment: A topos that would satisfy your criteria is the effective topos, but I don't see how the sequence $(F_n)_n$ would be computable (each $F_n$ is computable, but the sequence itself doesn't seem to be). P.S.: The discussion about $\Omega$ is a red herring.

Comment: @AndrejBauer The effective topos doesn't work because I need countable choice to fail.

Comment: You could use the topos constructed by James Henson and myself in which $\mathbb{R}$ is countable. I still don't see how you're going to define $F$, though. There's lots of excluded middle in the definition you wrote.

Comment: @AndrejBauer I think we need the internal $\mathbb R$ to correspond to external $\mathbb R^c$, but the morphisms $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ to correspond externally to all the classically continuous functions.

Comment: @AndrejBauer There's a topos in which $\mathbb R$ is countable? So that open problem has been settled then.

Comment: I don't think that can be done. If $h \in \mathsf{Hom}(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$ then $h(0) \in \mathbb{R}$, so if every classically continuous function appears in $ \mathsf{Hom}(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$ then all classical reals will appear in $\mathbb{R}$. Maybe I misunderstand your idea.

Comment: @AndrejBauer I mean all classically continuous functions $\mathbb R^c \to \mathbb R^c$.

Comment: Yes, James and I need to finish up the paper, so far this talk is available: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4CBFUojXoq4

Comment: @AndrejBauer Did you see my response about $\mathsf{Hom}(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$?

Comment: Yes, but I have nothing to say at the moment. I would find it rather incredible if such a topos existed.

Comment: Title of @AndrejBauer's talk referenced [above](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/437215/has-an-uncomputable-variant-of-the-cantor-staircase-ever-been-used-in-constructi#comment1126897_437215):  [The countable reals](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4CBFUojXoq4).